# Can Android app have a different name depending on locale/carrier?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization, android-manifest, google-play

On Android it is possible to have different resources depending on the locale or carrier. The app name specified in the manifest can reference a string from these resources.

What I'm wondering is:

- Will this actually work? Will the app name change depending on the locale/carrier?
- How will the name appear on the Market? Will the Market app pick up on the users settings and show the correct name? Which name will be used in the web version of the Market?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes,it works.Exactly in the way [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) says.

If your locale is say japan then android will search for the string resource at

```
res/values-ja/strings.xml
```

If resource is not there then it will search in `res/values/strings.xml`

I tested it and it really works

Comment: Can you comment on the Android Market behaviour?

Comment: In Google Play, the store listing information can be localized based on language and in some cases language+region (e.g. en-UK). That is done through the web interface, not in application code.